# How to use vim substitution command with sed?

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I want to convert a file such as ...

```
X,Y,id,
7.6245541,51.9556144,4064462
7.6248384,51.9556227,4064462
7.6250697,51.9556376,4064462
```

... into the following format using regular expressions.

```
X,Y,id,
"lat" : 7.6245541, "lon" : 51.9556144,
"lat" : 7.6248384, "lon" : 51.9556227,
"lat" : 7.6250697, "lon" : 51.9556376,
"lat" : 7.6256435, "lon" : 51.9557072,
```

The following substitution command works perfect in vim:

```
:%s#\(\d*\.\d*\)\(,\)\(\d*\.\d*\)\(,\)\(\d*\)$#"lat" : \1\2 "lo" : \3\4#g
```

How can I use *sed* to do the same? I would be happy if I can used the extend expression mode (sed parameter `-r` to avoid escaping the round brackets). Here is what I tried:

```
sed -r 's#(\d*\.\d*)(,)(\d*\.\d*)(,)(\d*)$#"lat" : \1\2 "lo" : \3\4#gw output.csv' input.csv
```

The original content is printed to the shell and nothing has changed.

Comment: regex supported by vim is much more powerful than sed's.  e.g. +/- look behind/ahead, `\zs \ze`, multiline, dotall..... if you just want to avoid to type \, vim has `very magic` option.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using `#` because of quotation issues; here is a shorter solution:

```
sed -i 's/^\([0-9.]*\),\([0-9.]*\),.*/ "lat" : \1, "lon" : \2,/g' filename.csv
```

The `-i` means to convert the file in place.

You might also do something for the first line though. To achieve this, add `X` before the first `0`and `Y` before the second `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` instead of `sed`

```
awk -F, '/^[0-9]/ {$0="\"lat\" : "$1", \"lon\" : "$2","}1' file
X,Y,id,
"lat" : 7.6245541, "lon" : 51.9556144,
"lat" : 7.6248384, "lon" : 51.9556227,
"lat" : 7.6250697, "lon" : 51.9556376,
```

This gives a simple to read/understand solution.  Using back reference and and complex regex makes it difficult to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
sed 's#^\([0-9]\+.[0-9]\+\),\([0-9]\+.[0-9]\+\).*# "lat" : \1, "lon" : \2,#g' input.csv
```

Comment: The commata at the end of the line is missing.

Comment: @JJD Simply add a comma after `\2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like this:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+),[0-9]+/"lat" : \1, "lon" : \2,/' data > output.txt
```

Where data is the file containing the original data and `>` redirects the output to `output.txt'.` `\1` and `\2` are expanded by the content of the first and second group inside of the regular expression.

you can also do this directly with the `-i` option to do it In place.

```
sed -i -r 's/([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+),[0-9]+/"lat" : \1, "lon" : \2,/' data
```